# Why when the timer is counting down it's never showing 0 on the seconds?

Tags: c#, winforms

I didn't wait but I'm guessing that the same problem is with the minutes.
When the timer is counting down and the seconds are getting 1 it's changing to 59 instead first sowing 0. I'm not sure about the logic of a timer if it should show the 0 when counting up/down or not.

When it's counting up it's working fine, It's showing 0 after the 59.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (countUpCheckbox.Checked)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    seconds += 1;

                    if (seconds == 60)
                    {
                        seconds = 0;
                        minutes += 1;
                    }

                    if (minutes == 60)
                    {
                        minutes = 0;
                        hours += 1;
                    }

                    richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
                }));
            }

            if (countdownCheckbox.Checked)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    seconds -= 1;

                    if (seconds == 0)
                    {
                        seconds = 59;
                        minutes -= 1;
                    }

                    if (minutes == 0)
                    {
                        minutes = 59;
                        hours -= 1;
                    }

                    richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
                }));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (seconds == 0) { seconds = 59;` Here you set seconds to 59 once it reach 0.

Comment: because you told it that when seconds reach 0 to change seconds to 59 *before* it gets displayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2), and let it calculate minutes/seconds:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (countUpCheckbox.Checked)
        {
            timespan += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }

        if (countdownCheckbox.Checked)
        {
            timespan -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", timespan.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), timespan.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), timespan.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
    }));
}
```

Initialize it in your class like below:

```
private TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(0);
```

Comment: [`TimeSpan.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.add#remarks) and [`TimeSpan.Subtract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.subtract#remarks) does not modify `TimeSpan` instance.

Comment: @PetSerAl Good catch. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your function you need to give it a chance to display 0, and check for seconds going to *below* 0 before wrapping back to 59, hence...

```
        ...
        if (countdownCheckbox.Checked)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                seconds -= 1;

                if (seconds == -1)   // <<<< check for -1 instead of 0
                {
                    seconds = 59;
                    minutes -= 1;
                }
                if (minutes == -1)   // <<<< And as you say, same for mins
                {
                    minutes = 59;
                    hours -= 1;
                }
                ...
```

Note that for this to work, `seconds` and `minutes` need to be declared as `signed` numerical values, not `unsigned`.